# Adding Attachment file to an external list item using AJAX throws Internal Server Error

Tags: ajax, list, external

i'm working with Sharepoint-hosted apps with OData. I am trying to add attachment file to a list item after the item is created using its BdcIdentity but i am getting the error below:

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{"error":{"code":"-2146232832,Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang\":"en-US","value":"The List item must be saved to the content database before adding an attachment. To resolve this problem, save the list item and then add the attachment."}}}","status":500,"statusText":"Internal Server Error"}
```

Code to create the list item:

```
url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('tbl_FeedbackDetails')/Items/",
type: "POST",
headers: {
    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
    "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
},
data: JSON.stringify(details),
success.....
```

---

Below is my code after the item is created (im running this code inside the success function of the fist ajax call):

```
var queryUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/lists/GetByTitle('ListName')/GetItemByStringId('BdcIdentity')/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='filename')";

$.ajax({
    url: queryUrl,
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: buffer,
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()    
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        console.log('Attachement Added Successfully');
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log("Failure:" + error.status + "," + error.statusText);
        console.log('Error full-text: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
```

The first call was successful in creating the list item. Am I doing things right?